# reading from serial \ Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm working with the serial Matlab but I need help.
On serial matlab I read a number of bits sent from one device, and I need to take only a few bits and not all. The "fread" I read all the bits together instead I would like to do a background check on each received bit as I do?
Let me explain I have a number of bits, which is contained in my package:

```
0xAA length payload
```

In order I would like to read from the serial 0xAA, if the received bit is equal to 0xAA, read length, and so on, but the fread reads me all the bits together. How can I do this control?

Answer (score 0):

Fread has a size parameter, which allows you to set the maximum number of bytes.

Comment: It may be interesting this little code that I did, the problem was the quickly reading because the impression is that the bits are read together instead are read one by one. THANK YOU SO MUCH.
      while (true)
        A=fread(s,1)          
      
        if length(A) == 1 && A==170
            
            B=fread(s,1,'uint16');
            
            if(length(B) == 1 && B==42)
                C = fread(s,2);
                
            end
       end